# Add all the elements of multiple ArrayList objects into a single ArrayList object

Tags: java, arraylist

In my case I have 4 ArrayList objects as below:

```
ArrayList<MyProduct> lstStyle;
ArrayList<MyProduct> 2ndStyle;
ArrayList<MyProduct> 3rdStyle;
ArrayList<MyProduct> 4thStyle;
```

I want to add all the elements in each ArrayList into a new **ArrayList** called *Style*.

```
ArrayList<MyProduct> Style;
```

Can I do this without looping each ArrayList?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [List#addAll(Collection c)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) method

```
Style.addAll(lstStyle);
Style.addAll(2ndStyle);
Style.addAll(3rdStyle);
Style.addAll(4thStyle);
```

Ofcourse, you need to instantiate all the lists first, otherwise you'll face a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 3):

```
Collections.addAll(Style, lstStyle, 2ndStyle, 3rdStyle, 34thStyle);
```

Comment: Collections.addAll adds all of the specified elements to the specified collection.  Elements to be added may be specified individually or as an array.

Answer (score 0):

Use `addAll` method

```
ArrayList<MyProduct> Style;

 Style.addAll(lstStyle);
 Style.addAll(2ndStyle);
 Style.addAll(3rdStyle);
 Style.addAll(4thStyle);
```